# ORM supporting mapping of generic types

Tags: c#, .net, orm

Are there ORM tools for .NET supporting mapping of generic types?

I imagine at least two possible mapping scenarios:

- Mapping of particular generic type instances
- Mapping of all possible generic instances (based on constraints & other mapped types).

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying out [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) the last couple of months, and I'm pretty sure it can do that. We've certainly got generic lists as properties on objects. I'm not sure that I completely understand your second requirement. I've implement a generic repository that takes any type, and that works fine, if that's the sort of thing you are talking about?

Comment: Note that Fluent NHibernate compliments NHibernate (very well), but you could use plain NHibernate without Fluent.

Comment: Also note that Ayende posted this in 2007. http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/14/NHibernate-and-Generic-Entities.aspx. I haven't needed to use Generic types in my models, but it might help you get a feel for the issues with mapping generics in NH.